# Selecting image from gallery giving me an error Load Failed

Tags: android

When i am trying to select image from the gallery it is giving me an error saying Load Failed.In some mobile phones only it is coming like that (like one plus) Can any body help me to solve this issue.Thank you

```
     private void openGalleryForImageSelection()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    try
    {
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY);
    }
    catch(Throwable e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,getResources().getString(R.string.image_error),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (((requestCode == IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY) || (requestCode == IMAGE_FROM_CAMERA)) && (Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode))
    {
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY)
        {
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
        }
        cropTheImage();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: So where's your code?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added my code. Can you please check and suggest me a solution to resolve this issue!

Comment: where is cropTheImage() function

Answer (score 0):

```
 void selectImage() {    
Intent intent = new Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(
    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
    IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY);
}



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
        null);
        Cursor cursor =cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
        Bitmap bm;

        file = new File(selectedImagePath);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
        int scale = 1;
        while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
        && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
        scale *= 2;
        options.inSampleSize = scale;
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void openGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
            PICK_IMAGE);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {

        try {
            taken = "gallery";
            selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            columnindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            file_path = cursor.getString(columnindex);
            // Log.e("Attachment Path:", attachmentFile);
            // tv_attach.setText(file_path);
            URI = Uri.parse("file://" + file_path);
            image_path = file_path;
            cursor.close();
            if (resultCode == 0) {
                dialog_camera.dismiss();
            } else {
                dialog_camera.dismiss();    
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

Comment: Could you please mention what are these changes and why these are required?